# printing IP address and subnet mask from a string by Java

Tags: parsing, ip-address

I use following expression to get IP and subnet from each string:

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5]) ([2-5]\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d)");
   Matcher match = pattern.matcher(inpS);
   while(match.find()) {
     System.out.println("\nIP found: "+match.group() );
```

The problem is that sometimes it shows correct result, e.g.
IP found: 10.181.0.2 255.255.255.128

but sometimes last digit in subnet mask is not shown e.g:
IP found: 10.181.0.251 255.255.255.24

What could be wrong?

Comment: looks like it relates to regex for subnet mask, would be thankful if someone share regex to match correctly subnet mask in Java

Answer (score 0):

I found the following regex in O'Reilly's *Regular Expressions Cookbook*, page 470:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])"+" (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])");
```

Answer (score 0):

In `[01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d` the first alternative will match 24 and the regex engine thinks it's done. You want to put the most specific alternative before the more general fallback pattern.